# setting up NODE_PATH

Tags: node.js, npm

I installed `nvm`, and used that to upgrade `node`: `nvm install 4.2.1`.
I updated `.bashrc` to export `NODE_PATH=$HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules`.

My immediate goal is to install hubot, following [these instructions](https://github.com/slackhq/hubot-slack). The install command succeeds: `npm install -g hubot coffee-script yo generator-hubot`

However the installed commands can't find their libraries:

```
$ yo hubot
module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'os-tmpdir'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/john/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/osenv/osenv.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
```

When I install each missing lib, it's found. So I end up with this situation:

```
# We already have two copies of os-tmpdir, why isn't it found??
$ find /home/john/.nvm/ -name "*tmpdir*"
/home/john/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/generator-hubot/node_modules/os-tmpdir
/home/john/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/osenv/node_modules/os-tmpdir

# Just install it again:
$ npm install -g os-tmpdir

# Now we have three copies! But it's being found.
$ find /home/john/.nvm/ -name "*os-tmpdir*"
/home/john/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/generator-hubot/node_modules/os-tmpdir
/home/john/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/osenv/node_modules/os-tmpdir
/home/john/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/os-tmpdir
```

Why isn't there a single `node_modules` for node modules? Is there supposed to be `node_modules` nested under `node_modules` nested under `node_modules` ... ?

Comment: it should have `/Users/sean/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.2/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/os-tmpdir`   installed

Comment: yes, this is how node work, but in npm 3.0, the node_modules will be flattened. which is a good news

Comment: @Sean, that sounds like good news indeed. You say it _should have_, why doesn't it, in my case? Am I doing something wrong? Why are modules ending up in `~/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [npm 3.0.0 release notes](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.0.0):

> Your dependencies will now be installed maximally flat. Insofar as is
>   possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and THEIR
>   dependencies will be installed in your project's node_modules folder
>   with no nesting. **You'll only see modules nested underneath one another
>   when two (or more) modules have conflicting dependencies.**

As for nvm...I've had path issues with it occasionally.  It does a pretty good job but I've had to fiddle a little, as you did.  Root causes for me in the past were a major upgrade for npm (like here, if that's what you've done) or a bad .npmrc file (whoops...).  The typical cache-clean, uninstall-reinstall stuff usually fixes it for me.

In this case the initial install was done before installing nvm and upgrading node. This fixes the problem:

```
$ npm uninstall -g hubot coffee-script yo generator-hubot
$ npm install -g hubot coffee-script yo generator-hubot
```

Comment: Expanded "typical ... stuff" to the actual commands ;-) Thanks!